# ImageButton não exibe fundo corretamente da imagem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

Tenho um sistema escolar com horário de cada curso e possuo uma activity onde o usuário deverá selecionar seu curso para ter acesso ao seu horário. Essa activity possui 5 `imageButtons` porém esses imageButtons não estão sendo exibidos corretamente, mesmo estando com fundo transparente na imagem desenhada originalmente, o fundo exibido no app é um cinza em volta do icone.

O código xml da activity é esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_iff"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botao_horario_informatica"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ti"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/botao_horario_agropecuaria" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botao_horario_agroindustria"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ai"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botao_horario_agropecuaria"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ap"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botao_horario_quimica"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tq"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/botao_horario_informatica"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/botao_horario_meio_ambiente"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ma"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/botao_horario_informatica" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Integrado"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

E o modo em que está aparecendo no aplicativo é esse:
[image: Repare no cinza em volta do icone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é o `background` padrão de um `imageButton`. Você pode alterá-lo mudando o atributo `android:background` do próprio componente. Algumas pessoas utilizam o background como `@null` (`android:background="@null"`) para remover o background da view. Funciona, mas não é o recomendável pois fará com que você perca os efeitos de clique na view, que são as animações que ocorrem quando a mesma é pressionada.

Para resolver este seu problema, faça isto:

```
<ImageButton
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```

O efeito de clique será mantido, e o background cinza irá sumir.

Comment: Problema resolvido, obrigado!